# Explicit form of the duals of a linear programming problems

Tags: matrices, inequality, optimization, linear-programming

> For the following linear programming, state its dual $(D_i)$ for
>   $i=1,2$:
>
> $$(P) \text{ } \text{ max}\left\{5x_1+6x_2 \mid \begin{matrix}
> -2x_1+x_2 \leq 2\\ 
> -x_1+x_2 \leq 4\\  2x_1+x_2 \geq 6\\  2x_1-3x_2 \leq 6\\  x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0 \end{matrix}\right\}$$

I'm very confused because it's saying "for $i=1,2$". That means they are looking for $2$ dual linear programmings, I think.

Before I can form the LP, I need to make sure that the inequalities are fine, they must be all "$\leq$". So I change the third inequation to: $-2x_1-x_2 \leq -6$.

Now I write them as a matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &  1 &  2\\ 
-1 &  1 &  4\\ 
-2 & -1 & -6\\ 
 2 & -3 &  6\\
 5 &  6 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$. Now I need to transpose this matrix, I get: $\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1 & -2 &  2 & 5\\ 
 1 &  1 & -1 & -3 & 6\\ 
 2 &  4 & -6 &  6 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Now I write this as a linear programming:

$$(D_1) \text{ } \text{ min}\left\{2y_1+4y_2-6y_3+6y_4 \mid \begin{matrix}
-2y_1-y_2-2y_3+2y_4 \geq 5\\ 
y_1+y_2-y_3-3y_4 \geq 6
\end{matrix}\right\}$$

---

My question is if my work is correct at all and how $(D_2)$ is supposed to be different?

Edit: Here is a screenshot, maybe there is a misunderstanding with "for $i=1,2$"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the dual correctly - there is only one dual problem for each primal problem.

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer, I was afraid no one would react because this topic doesn't seem to be common / liked here. Glad I did it correctly till here :D Maybe you can tell me what $D_2$ means and how it could be solved?

Comment: This may depend on what your text/source says. I think this refers to the constraints in the dual problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the task in my question. They probably take reference to the second part of the task, right? It's in German but maybe it's obvious by seeing? If not I will try to translate it precisely.

Comment: These are two separate problems. $D_1$ is the dual of $P_1$ and $D_2$ is the dual of $P_2$.

Comment: Great, thank you :) And @JeanMarie thanks for the nice edit!